# How to insert JSON data to PostgreSQL

Tags: database, go, psql

I have the json field like blow which I want to store in database

```
{
      id:          1
      name:        "test entity 1"
      description: "a test entity for some guy's blog"
      status: "passed"
      web_url: "http://localhost:3000"
      jobs: [{
         id:        "1"
         name:      "test1"
         status:    "passed"
        },
        {
         id:        "2"
         name:      "test2"
         status:    "passed"
        },
        {
         id:        "3"
         name:      "test3"
         status:    "failed"
       }]
    }
```

I proceed with one way like for creating table uses:

```
CREATE TABLE test3 (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR, description VARCHAR, status VARCHAR, web_url VARCHAR, jobs JSON[]);
```

and for Inserting data uses:

```
sqlStatement := `
            INSERT INTO jobs (id, name, description, status, web_url, jobs)
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
            ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
            SET status = $4
            RETURNING id`
        id := 0
        err = database.Db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, y[i].ID, y[i].Name, y[i].Description, y[i].Status, y[i].WebURL, jobsdata).Scan(&id)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
```

But won't work, need help!!

Getting errors:

```
panic: sql: converting argument $6 type: unsupported type handler.Jobs, a slice of struct
```

What i want:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM test3;
id |    name       |             description           | status  |       web_url          |                           jobs                           
------+------------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 1 | test entity 1 | a test entity for some guy's blog | passed | https://localhost:3000 | {id: "1",name: "test1", status: "passed"},{id: "2",name: "test2", status: "passed"},{id: "3",name: "test3", status: "failed"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicates, you're trying to bind the sixth value from an unsupported data type, `handler.Jobs`.  You haven't told us what this type is, but from the error, it's clear that it does not implement the [`driver.Valuer`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interface, so it won't work, because it has no way of knowing how to represent that value to the database.

You'll need to implement that interface, by adding a `Value()` method to the `handler.Jobs` type, or use a different data type.

Comment: When i'm trying to print jobsdata using (log.Infof("--->", jobsdata)) , i get this

`INFO[0004] --->%!(EXTRA handler.Jobs=[{36884 success aws-cluster} {36885 success openebs-aws-deploy} {36903 failed app-upgrade-deployment}])`

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure how that's relevant? Is there a point you're trying to make?

Answer (score -1):

sqlx has a type [JSONText](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/types#JSONText) in [github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/types](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/master/types/types.go) that will do what you need.

[Example](https://gist.github.com/rrafal/09534862e05cd98e4eb9b17dd5fcc1fc)